# Grow equal height to either child of a row widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-row, flutter-expanded

I am trying to render a row widget, where each row child will be a column with some children. For now I am just using the children of column as Text widget.

The column widget minimum height should be 200 and should grow based on the content of column children. If either children of the row is more than 200 , both the row children should have the same height of the highest

Attaching what I tried, I also tried using the IntrinsicHeight

```
Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
        Expanded(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 200),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.teal,
            child: const Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                 Text("Hello there, welcome to the flutter code"),
                 
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )),
        Expanded(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 200),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.tealAccent,
            child: const Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                 Text(
                      "Hello there, welcome to the flutter code. Trying to create a widget with a row of equal heights, The minimum height should be 200, if one side of the row is more than 200 , then Row's other component should be of the same height"),
                
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ))
          ],
        ),
```

[image]